# neo4j datetime formating with timezone

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have read the docs, and have concluded I must not understand English.

Example of datetime stamp creation:

```
   CREATE (account:User)
   SET account.createdDT=datetime()
   SET account.timezone="Greenwich"
```

I am assuming datetime is being created in GMT - correct?

I want to retrieve account.createdDT and display it in user timezone

```
   MATCH (account)
   RETURN account.createdDT
```

How can I format account.createdDT to shift to user's timezone and look normal to human beings?

```
   RETURN apoc.date.format(account.createdDT, "s", "MMM d yyyy", account.timezone),
   apoc.date.parse (account.createdDT, "s", "MMM d yyyy", account.timezone)
```

isn't working: Function call does not provide the required number of arguments: expected 0 got 1 and "Can't coerce to String"

I've also tried with America/New_York so I don't think it's the timezone value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datetime()` function is configurable, and can take a timezone, as in: `datetime({timezone:"Greenwich"})`, so there is no reason for `User` to have a separate `timezone` property.

Also, there are special [temporal APOC functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/3.4/temporal/temporal-conversions/) for formatting the [temporal values](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/) returned by [temporal functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/) like `datetime()`. You should be using the `apoc.temporal.format()` function.

For example:

```
CREATE (account:User)
SET account.createdDT=datetime({timezone:"America/New_York"})
RETURN
  apoc.temporal.format(account.createdDT, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'), 
  apoc.temporal.format(datetime({datetime: account.createdDT, timezone: "Greenwich"}), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'),  
  apoc.temporal.format(datetime({datetime: account.createdDT, timezone: "America/New_York"}), 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I resolved this.

I never did get apoc.date.parse or apoc.date.format to work with created Datetime().

However, this works great:

```
CREATE (account:User)
SET account.createdDT=Timestamp(), account.timezone="America/New_York"
RETURN apoc.date.format(account.createdDT, 'ms', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'), 
apoc.date.format(account.createdDT, 'ms', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', "Greenwich"),  
apoc.date.format(account.createdDT, 'ms', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', "America/New_York"),  
apoc.date.format(account.createdDT, 'ms', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', account.timezone)
```

Not sure why I can't get it to work with DateTime(), but will go with the flow...